# Unable to get parameter in query string in htacces

Tags: .htaccess

My request will come like /insights/papers-articles.html?view=papers&p=10&/abcdefgh&indcal=1
When i hit this url, it redirect me to /insights/papers-articles/papers-abcdefgh-3.html

I want indcal parameter so url will be /insights/papers-articles/papers-abcdefgh-10.html?indcal=1

I have used following rules :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&p=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+)&indcal=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html\?indcal=%6 [R=301,L]
```

But "indcal" parameter is not comming, Please help.

TIA.

This is complete rules

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&p=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html? [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&p=([^&\s]+)&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html? [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&q=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html? [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&q=([^&\s]+)&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html? [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?p=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/papers-%4-%3.html? [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&p=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+)&indcal=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html\?indcal=%6 [R=301,L]
```

Last rule is for above query.

Comment: Rule looks fine, just test in a separate browser.

Comment: anubhava it is redirecting on /insights/papers-articles/papers-abcdefgh-10.html not /insights/papers-articles/papers-abcdefgh-10.html?indcal=1

Comment: No it does work fine and redirects to `/insights/papers-articles/papers-abcdefgh-10.html?indcal=1` I have tested it.

Comment: i have checked it on different browser, not working, i also cleared history. is there any alternate rule for this.

Comment: That means you have other rules too. Post your complete .htaccess

Comment: No not in comments, no one can read it. Edit the question and provide code there.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&p=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+)&indcal=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html\?indcal=%6 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&p=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&p=([^&\s]+)&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&q=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?view=([^&\s]+)&q=([^&\s]+)&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3-%5-%4.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(insights)/(papers-articles)\.html\?p=([^&\s]+)&/([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/papers-%4-%3.html? [R=301,L]
```